# Saving choice of css file to LocalStorage, remembering this choice when page is refreshed or reopened

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried countless things, my mind is numb trying to find a solution from other questions and tutorials, could I please get some new eyes on this? Basically, I have a button that switches between two css files (for dark mode), I don't use CSS variables due to incompatiblity with IE11.

It needs to remember the choice, and when the page loads, it should load based on what is remembered.

Here is my javascript:

```
var defaultSS = './css/custom.css',
    altSS = './css/custom-dark.css',
    hrefAttr;

$('#css_toggle').click(function () {

  $('link').each(function(){
    hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href');
    if (hrefAttr.indexOf(defaultSS) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('href', altSS);

      console.log('Was:',hrefAttr);
      console.log('Now:',$(this).attr('href'));

    } else if (hrefAttr.indexOf(altSS) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('href', defaultSS);

      console.log('Was:',hrefAttr);
      console.log('Now:',$(this).attr('href'));
      document.cookie = $(this).attr('href');

    }
  });

});
```

and the button:

```
<button class="themetoggle-button" id="css_toggle">Theme Toggle</button>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: use cookies to store simple preference data

Comment: look at this example => https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

Comment: here is theory https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage.setItem(name, value)` to set a flag for dark mode, and then check for this flag being `true` after page load with `localStorage.getItem(name)`

If it's true, we just run the same code found inside the click function

```js
let defaultSS = './css/custom.css';
let altSS = './css/custom-dark.css';

$(window).on('load', () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') === 'true') {
    $('link').each(function() {
      let href = $(this).attr('href');

      if (href.includes(defaultSS)) {
        $(this).attr('href', altSS);
      }
    })
  }
});

$('#css_toggle').click(function() {
  $('link').each(function() {
    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href.includes(defaultSS)) {
      // Dark mode
      $(this).attr('href', altSS);
      localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'true');

      console.log('Was:', href);
      console.log('Now:', $(this).attr('href'));

    } else if (href.includes(altSS)) {
      // Light mode
      $(this).attr('href', defaultSS);
      localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'false');

      console.log('Was:', href);
      console.log('Now:', $(this).attr('href'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="themetoggle-button" id="css_toggle">Theme Toggle</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom.css">
```

---

Comment: Seems to make sense, I assume I need to set an onload attribute in my body tag?

Comment: You're using jQuery, so [`$(document).on('load', function() {...});`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) will fire when the entire page is ready

Comment: That's what I thought. I've used a console log function to verify the document is ready, but the event doesn't seem to be firing.

I've also verified localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') = true (when dark mode is selected).

Comment: Awesome. Appears to be working perfectly. Thankyou!